# AngularJs ng-messages in multiple languages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-messages` for displaying error messages to a form validation.
My app is multi-language, how can I use `ng-messages` in multi-language?

**html form**

```
<div class="messages" ng-messages="myForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
</div>
```

**messages.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
<p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
<p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>
```

**P.S.:** I'm using angular 1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

One quick (less maintainable in longer run) approach is to Have different js files of all messages per language (italian.js, english.js ..)
1) have multiple index pages as per language annd in index refer correpsonding locale js file 
2)On language selection change the index page ..sp automatically locale reference will change

replace "This field is required" with {{requiredMessage}}

in locale-english.js

```
controllersModule.controller('HeaderLocale', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.requiredMessage='This field is required';
}
```

in locale-italian.js

```
controllersModule.controller('HeaderLocale', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.requiredMessage='This field is required message in italian';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions, it is a great ideia and i offen use it, but my question was that if is it posible with ng-messages (angular-messages)

Answer (score 0):

its too late . but it may help someone else .I was wondering same . After some research i opted for [angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) library which helped me translate all view labels , server side messages and front end validations .

```
<p ng-message="required" translate="">required_msg </p>
<p ng-message="minlength" translate="">too_short_msg</p>
<p ng-message="maxlength" translate="">too_long_msg</p>
<p ng-message="email" translate="">invalid_email_msg</p>
<p ng-message="pattern" translate="">invalid_characters_msg</p>
```

And put the keys and values in locale file for all languages needed
 eg : locale-en.js

```
  "required_msg" : "This field is required" ,
  "too_short_msg" : "This field is too short",
  "too_long_msg" : "This field is too long",
  "invalid_email_msg" : "Enter valid email",
  "invalid_characters_msg" : "Invalid Characters"
```